# How do I Strip jQuery down to the bind function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I am listening to an iframe for a custom event, that the [wistia video frame](http://wistia.com/doc/embedding)  have labelled 'conversion'.

All I need is the bind function because jQuery is [slowing](http://xenforo.com/community/threads/jquery-is-slow-to-load.38964/) down my site loading time.

If there is no easy way to strip jQuery down to the bind function, then would it be possible to use addEventListener? The only problem I have there is that it tosses me an undefined error when I do that, probably because it doesn't understand what 'conversion' is.

```
setTimeout(
  function () {
    clearTimeout();
    ifr.wistiaApi.bind("conversion", function (t, v) {
      eml=v;
      sp('FreeBook');
    });
  }
, 1500);
```

Could someone help me crack this? Wistia's iframe embed documentation isn't good.

*Edit 1*

I am researching now to find out how to write my own “bind” function as suggested in the comments below, this is a much faster approach than striping JQuery.

*Edit 2* (response)

Hi Mark, I hadn't tested to make sure that JQuery was the cause of the slow down. All I knew is that when I added it to the site it definitely slowed down. But here is the loading time I tested just now with safari's web inspector: 1.41s, the next longest thing to load is a large image I have on the site: 711ms

Comment: Look at their source code, and write your own `bind` function.

Comment: To play devils advocate, what kind of profiling did you do that confirms that jQuery is indeed the culprit of your slow loading time?

Comment: I couldn't agree more with meagar. You aren't after the "jquery bind function", you are after the **functionality**, which is obviously not exclusive to jQuery but rather just another *javascript* technique. Frankly, you'll be better of learning what exactly the jQuery function is doing and reproduce the functionality you need rather than trying to rip some third-party code that you don't understand. This is the hazard of being dependent on frameworks -- they're shortcuts, but you have no idea what it is you're cutting if you don't learn it "by hand". Do yourself a favor and learn :D /pedantry

Comment: FYI, when(if) you do write your own function, don't call it "bind": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind -- jQuery stepped in it when they named this function, that's partly why it is deprecated in favor of `on`.

Comment: Hey guys, wow thanks for the response! If you wouldn't mind too much I am very busy at the moment could you explain what the bind function is doing to allow listening to custom events? Thanks very much for the help so far I don't ask questions often and I really like the community here.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery from a CDN? It's entirely possible that the CDN is just bogged down. Copy jQuery to your site and host it yourself. Then you are only at the mercy of your own bandwidth.

Comment: Hi invertedSpear, I am pulling it from a local directory. I'm sorry I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip down jQuery to bind, I would recommend Google Closure Compiler in the advanced setting. You wil find it on http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home . Add your code and the jQuery library and compile withe the advanced preset. This should strip the code down to the necessary functions.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately I end up with a lot more than just the bind function, 171 warnings and no way of really implementing the resulting code since closure-compiler also includes the iframe code which is partly executed on their servers. I would have no access to that an thus the video contained in the iframe would not load. The next attempts I tried failed with errors.

Comment: That's strange because I register only 115 warnings and there is a iframe but it is not connectiong to Google.

Comment: Are you pulling: http://fast.wistia.com/static/iframe-api-v1.js? This is the script for the api and is put in the head of the document. I used this in combination with JQuery.